# nmap not scanning for host

Tags: nmap, network-scanners

nmap keeps showing different and wrong results whenever I perform a scan to see how many hosts are up on my subnet. See the following scan reports.

The first scan I made was not with super user privilege. The second scan was made to see if it makes any difference if I had super user privilege. The third scan I made was specific for a particular IP address(which was up during first 2 scans as well but was not reported by it). Any Idea?

```
papagolf@Sierra ~ % nmap -sn 192.168.1.1-255

Starting Nmap 7.25BETA2 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-10-31 18:50 IST
Nmap scan report for www.netis.cc (192.168.1.1)
Host is up (0.0048s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.4
Host is up (0.00014s latency).
Nmap done: 255 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 19.31 seconds
papagolf@Sierra ~ % sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.1-255
[sudo] password for papagolf: 

Starting Nmap 7.25BETA2 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-10-31 18:51 IST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.4
Host is up.
Nmap done: 255 IP addresses (1 host up) scanned in 26.98 seconds
papagolf@Sierra ~ % sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.3    

Starting Nmap 7.25BETA2 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-10-31 18:52 IST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.3
Host is up (0.0030s latency).
MAC Address: B0:47:BF:AC:A6:C4 (Samsung Electronics)
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 16.78 seconds
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I don't think Nmap is showing "wrong" results to you. You are getting different results as expected, because **you are doing different scans**, even if you don't know that. Using Nmap is not like using a magic option combination that will give you straight away a definitive result. There exist different techniques because different devices in the network behave differently (routers, firewalls, different OS...), and also you might want to be more or less "invisible". Herein, the beauty of Nmap is its flexibility, that allows you to conduct many different scans to find what you need. Imagine it as a mapping tool that will give you X results with some options and Z results with some others. Then, it is your brain who should interpret them and come to conclusions. You only ran the basic command with all the default options, and there is much more to explore.

---

**[1]** You are doing only a ping scan, which by default will do the following:

- Send an `ICMP` echo request
- Send a `TCP ACK` packet to port `80`

*NOTE:* Newer Nmap versions (I believe yours included) also send a `TCP SYN` packet to port `443` and an `ICMP` timestamp request.

---

**[2]** If you are in the same network (and you are a super user), which in your case means the computer running Nmap has an IP like `192.168.1.X`, an `ARP` request will be used instead. If you use `Wireshark` you can see the `ARP` packet exchanges.

---

**[3]** Lastly, the default behaviour of **[1]** uses RAW packets for the `ICMP` echo and the `TCP ACK`, so when you use an unprivileged user then Nmap cannot use this technique. Instead, Nmap will send a `TCP SYN` packet to port `80`, by using *connect* as your normal user applications will do.

---

If you understand how Nmap is working (**[1]**, **[2]** and **[3]**) then you can see why you are getting different results.

In your first scan, both computers (`192.168.1.1` and `192.168.1.4`) accepted the `TCP` connection. This used to be a very noisy scan, because applications will log the fact that you have accessed them. But you got what you wanted: seeing they were alive. Note that you can configure this type of scan when running Nmap as a super user (so even when you are a super user you can use **[3]** instead of **[1]** or **[2]**) and you will have obtained exactly the same result.

Your second scan sent an `ACK` to port `80` and an `ICMP` echo, and `192.168.1.1` ignored it. This could mean that it has a firewall in place. On the other hand, `192.168.1.4` responded either to the `ACK` or the `ICMP` echo. If you were in the same network (`192.168.1.0`), then `ARP` would have been used instead (see **[2]**)... but if that was the case, for some reason `192.168.1.1` would have not responded to your `ARP` request, which I find unusual. Therefore, I would guess that you were not in the same network.

In your third scan, in my opinion `192.168.1.3` should have given you the same results as it did in the second scan. The fact that `192.168.1.3` did not show up in the second scan might respond to different facts - perhaps it was connected through wifi and it was down? It happens to my phone sometimes when it disconnects automatically to save power. Did you get these results consistently? You should run more verbose scans to see why exactly Nmap is interpreting network hints the way it does.

Finally, if you are serious about learning the tool, I strongly recommend you to get **Fyodor's Nmap book**. It is great not only to understand how Nmap works, but also some computer networks behaviour and other tricks. For example, you could use `-n` to skip reverse `DNS` lookups and speed up your test. You could also try different ping ports (from the default `80`) and different types of ping.

Comment: That's a very good answer. Why, out of interest by the way, doesn't nmap use ARP for the hosts in the same network for unpriv users too, to perform -sn for example? I checked and arping command doesn't require root privs.

Comment: Never mind, I think I found the answer by performing nmap without sudo for the whole subnet rather than just one IP address. For the IPs that don't exist in the ARP cache, an ARP req is sent first. --disable-arp-ping flag doesn't seem to stop ARPs going out though, which still is a mystery to me.

Comment: I think you **do** need root to send raw Ethernet packets - otherwise you could attach IP data to your raw Ethernet packet and send a raw IP packet with no root. When you did the nmap without sudo, you did a 3-way handshake `connect()` to each address, and during this process, your OS NEEDs to determine each destination MAC address to send them data, so it has to send an ARP request as it would do normally (but it is not sent by Nmap!) This is why the nmap flag didn't stop ARP requests, nmap has no control in the same way as nmap cannot stop the client `ACK` in during the `connect()`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your second scan too 192.168.1.1 is not shown up and the mode of your scan is

**-sn -- ping only no port scan**

there should be some problem which icmp connectivity which sometimes makes this host ( 192.168.1.3 ) looks as if not up

Comment: So How do I perform a reliable scan?

Comment: What do you want to do ?  Just find the alive host

Comment: Yes. I just want to have a reliable list of all the hosts alive on my network. But performing an individual scan against each IP address sounds like a hectic job.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between privileged and unprivileged scan, but only for port scans (`SYN`, `ACK`, etc). The difference is that the privileged one will craft a raw TCP packet against the target IP, meanwhile the unprivileged scan will rely on the `connect` syscall. It shouldn't affect discovered hosts, just speed (For details about why is that, you should refer to [nmap documentation](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-techniques.html))

The reason why the third scan discovered a host the other two scans didn't may vary. Some hosts don't respond ping packets at all (It shouldn't be a reliable scan unless you're 100% sure the host will respond), some hosts have a minimum delay between responses, dropped packets if the network is overloaded, a firewall, etc

If you want a realiable list of all available hosts you should use more than one type of scan, but the scans you may need depend on the precision level you want, the knowledge of the network you have and the amount of time you can spend

A simple scan that should give you better results could be

```
sudo nmap -PS --disable-arp-ping 192.168.1.0/24
```

That will list all discovered hosts using a TCP SYN scan against most common ports. If that doesn't fit your needs (Maybe there are some hosts blocking all common ports scanned) you should try with more advanced scans like:

```
sudo nmap -PA 192.168.1.0/24
sudo nmap -sA -p1-65535 192.168.1.0/24
sudo nmap -sN -p1-65535 192.168.1.0/24
sudo nmap -PO 192.168.1.0/24
```

Not all scans will discover every host, that depends on too much things

PS: If you want more detail of what's going on during the scan you could use the flags `--reason`, `--packet-trace` and/or `-vv`. Those flags will enable a more verbose output indicating the reason a port is marked `open`/`closed`/`filtered`/`unfiltered`, the packets sent to each host and general purpouse verbosity respectively

Comment: Note that -PS will not likely work against, e.g. a Linux system with iptables in place. In that case, the default -PA might have better chances

Comment: I have also realised there are some wrong facts in this answer...

Comment: @user1156544 It would be great if you actually tell what is wrong or at least edit the answer...

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Well, one thing is that if you `sudo nmap -PS x.x.x.x` and x.x.x.x is in your same network as the OP said in a comment, nmap will actually do a -PR instead, so the PS is actually never done!  I think this answer has good intentions but fails in some actual operative details

Comment: @user1156544 Edited my answer with your comment so `-PS` scans is not actually turned into a `-PR` scan on local networks

Comment: I normally use `--send-ip`. Note this also happens in `-PA`, etc And that `-sA` and `-sN` will not have a different effect in what the OP is asking